# Finding an image with partial name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image inside a div as follows:

```
<div id="testdiv">
   <div class=".kl"> </div>
   <img src="../../testimage.png"/>
</div>
```

I want to test if the image is present or not in the div . 
I have wriiten a jquery condition which is showing true for all conditions:

```
if ($("#testdiv").children('img').attr('src','testimage.png')) {
alert('image found');
}

if ($("#testdiv").children('img').attr('src','dummyimage.png')) {
alert('image found');
}
```

The control is going inside the second **'if'** condition which is incorrect because **dummyimage.png** is not present in the **"testdiv"**.
How to find out just by the image name if its present or not inside a div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't searching by attribute, it's *setting* an attribute.

If you want to search by an attribute ending in a given value, you can use the [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) (`[name$=value-it-ends-with]`):

```
if ($("#testdiv img[src$='testimage.png']").length) {
    // yes, it's there
} else {
    // no, it isn't
}
```

There's also the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`*=` instead of `$=`) which will match a sbustring anywhere, not just at the end. And [`^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) which matches only at the beginning. More in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out all images src [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the specified string literal. Then check its [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property

```
var hasImages = $("#testdiv > img").filter(function(){
    return this.src.endsWith('testimage.png');
}).length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check in this way:

```
 if ($("#testdiv").children('img').attr('src').endsWith('testimage.png')) {
    alert('image found');
 }

if ($("#testdiv").children('img').attr('src').endsWith('dummyimage.png')) {
    alert('image found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.attr(key, value)` attempts to SET the value to the element, rather than checking if the attribute value is the provided value. So the if() got a true whenever it can set "dummyimage.png" to the image src. This is probably not what you wanted.

Instead, you should use `.attr('src') == 'dummyimage.png'` (or better, use `.indexOf()` or a regular expression instead of `==`) inside your if. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Check image exists or not

```
if($("#div").find('[name="ElementNameHere"]').length>0)
{
    // image exists 
}
else
{
   // image does not  exists 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You just set id for img. And use this jquery.

```
if ( $('#myElement').length ) {
// it exists 
}
```